# Is there a NATIVE password manager and generator for Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: 16.04, password

I already looked for a lot of usefuls password generators, but what I want to know if this distribution has a **build-in** or **native** tool. Thanks in advance.

*Edit 1:* My main doubt was if there is some software already installed on Ubuntu 16.04. I already know and use **Seahorse**, but it doesn't generate any strong web passwords.

Of course other apps could work too, like @Gus in The Netherlands and @Ravexina recommended (indirectly) **Keepass**, but that is not what I am curious about

I thought there was something else there that I am missing.

Comment: @Ravexina sometimes it can be really difficult to find an answer if you don't know how to ask the question. I'm gonna edit to clarify.

Comment: The command-line tool `pwgen` isn't included out-of-the box but it's in the "main" repository if that works for you. I'll write an answer when this question is reopened.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there are no password generators installed by default in Ubuntu. However you can install third party tools to achieve this as suggested in other answers.

Answer (score 0):

I have a couple of years experience with several versions of the open-source (OSI certified) password manager KeePass on Windows and the last few weeks with the latest version on Ubuntu. I can recommend Keepass.
It is available for most other platforms (Windows and Apple devices, Android etc.) and uses the same encrypted database (so you can sync via the cloud).
See http://www.keepass.info/download.html.
For Ubuntu Keepass2 is the best version (works better than KeepassX(C) from the repository. To obtain the latest and best version of Keepass2 see http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2017/04/install-the-latest-keepass2-2-35-in-ubuntu-16-04-16-10-14-04/.
I sync my Keepass database (and Firefox browser and Thunderbird mail) between Ubuntu en Windows computers via the cloud and this works great. 
If you decide to go for Keepass2, the desired user interface language file may possibly be found on: http://www.keepass.info/translations.html.
In my installation this file (after unpacking) must be placed in /usr/lib/keepass2/ where the KeePass.config.xml and KeePass.exe.config files are located.

Success,
Gus

Comment: I gotta ask - what is it that makes Keepass2 not native, in your opinion?

Comment: Maybe I got that wrong. I said that because for Ubuntu 16.04 LTS it isn't available via the Ubuntu Software app from the Ubuntu repositories (it was for 14.04 LTS). I will look up the definition of native.

Answer (score 0):

I use something like this to generate random string. Argument is the number of characters.

```
#!/bin/bash

char_count="$1"

cat /dev/urandom | tr -dc 'a-zA-Z0-9' | fold -w $char_count | head -n 1
```

Usage:

```
$ ./random 15
gsbN9PCD4bo7Gxs
```

Answer (score -1):

use `sudo apt install pass` to install the Linux native password manager (command-line based).